# Widget screenshot with custom dimensions

Tags: flutter

I want to take a screenshot of a widget, but this image is saving in my gallery in 1179x1278 dimensions. I want this image to be saved as 500x500. I'm using [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) [share_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus) and [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider)  libraries.

Codes:

```
Future<void> _takeScreenshot(
  {required BuildContext context, required Widget shareWidget}) async {
final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

ScreenshotController()
    .captureFromWidget(shareWidget)
    .then((Uint8List bytes) async {
  final Directory dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
  final String ts = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  final String filePath = '${dir.path}/$ts.png';
  await XFile.fromData(bytes).saveTo(filePath);
  await Share.shareXFiles(
    [XFile(filePath)],
    sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
  );
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flutter_image_compress package to resize the image before saving it.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';

Future<void> _takeScreenshot({
  required BuildContext context,
  required Widget shareWidget,
}) async {
  final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;

  ScreenshotController().captureFromWidget(shareWidget).then((Uint8List 
bytes) async {
    final Directory dir = await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    final String ts = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
    final String filePath = '${dir.path}/$ts.png';

    // Resize the image to 500x500 pixels
    final Uint8List resizedBytes = await 
FlutterImageCompress.compressWithList(
      bytes,
      minHeight: 500,
      minWidth: 500,
    );

    // Save the resized image to file
    await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(resizedBytes, name: 
'screenshot_$ts');

    // Share the saved image
    await Share.shareFiles(
      [filePath],
      subject: 'Share Screenshot',
      sharePositionOrigin: box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero) & box.size,
    );
  });
}
```

Make sure to include the required dependencies in your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  screenshot: ^0.3.0
  share_plus: ^3.0.4
  path_provider: ^2.0.5
  flutter_image_compress: ^1.0.2
  image_gallery_saver: ^2.1.1
```

Let me know if you need more context on the code, i think it's pretty straight-forward. Good luck!

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer @Locoz . In the code example you wrote, the width I want is the size I want, but the height is not the size I want. For example, when I type 500x500, the image is saved in 500x523 dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'll update another answer